# Is there exist "_emit" or equivalent in Rust inline assembly?

Tags: assembly, rust, inline-assembly

In Visual Studio we can generate opcode bytes with the "_emit" directive.

Also, in GCC we can use something like:

```
asm __volatile__ (".byte 0x12");
```

Can we do something similar in Rust inline assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust's standard inline asm is, unfortunately, basically GAS (with intel syntax by default), so

```rust
#![no_main]

#[no_mangle]
unsafe extern "cdecl" fn main() {
    core::arch::asm!(".byte 12h");
}
```

will generate

```
main:
  push rax
  .byte 18
  pop rax
  ret
```

which is the same as in C.

Comment: Reminder for future readers: as always, you need to declare clobbers and/or input/output operands to correctly describe your asm to the compiler, whether you assemble machine-code bytes into the output manually with `.byte` or `.int`, or with mnemonics like `nop` or `int3`.  At least a `"memory"` clobber is often a good idea to stop loads/stores from reordering with your asm statement.

Comment: Does LLVM's built-in assembler accept `12h` instead of `0x12`?  It doesn't in a stand-alone `.s` file with `clang -c` (regardless of `.intel_syntax noprefix`; as expected that doesn't matter.)  Interesting if it does with Rust.  BTW, `12h` is the opcode for `adc r8, r/m8`, so it consumes at least one byte after as its modr/m.  If you follow it with a bunch of 1-byte NOPs, it consumes 5 of them as `12 90 90 90 90 90    adc    dl,BYTE PTR [rax-0x6f6f6f70]`.  A realistic example might be something like `.byte 0xF3, 0x0F, 0x01, 0xEA` `SAVEPREVSSP` for toolchains too old for CET_SS insns.